# es6 object destructuring, assign into new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destruction

new to es6 here.  is there any way to shorten this code with es6 features? i'm trying to destructure from an object and put those pulled properties into a new object.

```
    const { Height, Width, Location, MapAttachmentTypes, 
ZoomLevelAdjustment, CustomPushPins, CenterPushpinStyle, ScaleFactor } = args;
        const body = {
          Height,
          Width,
          Location,
          MapAttachmentTypes,
          ZoomLevelAdjustment,
          CustomPushPins,
          CenterPushpinStyle,
          ScaleFactor
        };
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
const  body = { Height, Width, Location, MapAttachmentTypes, ZoomLevelAdjustment, CustomPushPins, CenterPushpinStyle, ScaleFactor } = args;
```

Comment: I *think* this has been asked before, at least a couple of times; did you [search](/help/searching) thoroughly? *(not my dv)*

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" ?

Comment: What does your `args` object look like?  Does it destructure as you expect?

Comment: Are you trying to actually pull the properties in as new into `body` or references to the relevant props of `args`?

Answer (score -3):

```
    // new syntax
    const body = {
        ...args
    };
    // es5
    const body = Object.assign({}, args);
```

Comment: This will copy **all** of the properties of `args`, not just the selected properties.

Comment: This will return everything from `args`, not just the specified keys.

Comment: Indeed, in case it is not wanted,  the first example in the question will do the trick.

Comment: But the question is how to shorten the syntax to not repeat all the keys like in the first example ;)

Comment: Spread properties are not part of ES6 and `Object.assign` is not part of ES5.

Comment: @FelixKling: Details, details... ;-)